# How to center vertical text within a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple bar graph using an unordered list.  I've got text within each of the bars and have it rotated so that it is vertical.  The graph is responsive so the width of the bars shrink when the screen is shrunk.

```
<div id="chart">
  <ul id="bars">
    <li><div data-percentage="85" class="bar"><span>HTML</span></div></li>
    <li><div data-percentage="85" class="bar"><span>CSS</span></div></li>
    <li><div data-percentage="60" class="bar"><span>jQuery</span></div></li>
    <li><div data-percentage="60" class="bar"><span>PHP</span></div></li>
    <li><div data-percentage="35" class="bar"><span>MySQL</span></div></li>
    <li><div data-percentage="85" class="bar"><span>Worpress</span></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS and jQuery associated can be found with the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8QVa6/

When the bars width decrease, the text is cut off to the right, any idea what CSS I'm missing to keep it centered the entire time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `top: 50%` with `position: relative` on the label `span` elements. It needs to be `display: block` for this to work.

```
#chart #bars li .bar span {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

    position: relative;
    top: 50%;

    margin-top: -10px; /* about half line height */
}
```

The `margin: -10px` is neccessary to compensate the line height after rotation. You can leave it away if it's not so bad if a label is not exactly centered.

See the fork: http://jsfiddle.net/Nb53Z/2/

Comment: This worked with the horizontal movement, but instead of vertically centered, is there anyway to vertically align top and leave like a 10-15px padding?

Comment: Actually, forget it. I like it the way you come up with! Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to ask you for an image showing the expected result because your Q title and your previous comment seem a bit conflicting. :o Is my solution correct or are there details I missed?

Comment: No you're solution is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `display:inline-table` on the span, you need to add `display: table;` to the parent

```
#chart #bars li .bar {
  display: table;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Still the responsiveness result ends up being totally messy. Due to the overall styles.